# Find the dimension of an (explicit) projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

I have to compute the dimension of :
$$
 X=V(xz-y^2,xz-xw,yz-yw,z^2-zw) \subset \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})
$$
My idea was to compute irreducible components of this algebraic sets and intersect with some easy hypersurface like $V(x)$ and compute the dimension of an irreducible component which shall be dimX-1.

It could be a good idea or there is a smarter method?
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: The first element in your ideal is not homogeneous. Should it be $y^2$ instead of $y$?

Comment: yes off course !!

Comment: The strategy you suggest seems reasonable, although once you know all the irreducible components it will probably be immediate to read off their degree. Maybe a cruder but quicker way would be to observe that since you are in $\mathbf P^3$ there are very few possibilities for the answer; you can eliminate one possibility very quickly, and find a component whose dimension equals the largest remaining possibility also without too much trouble.